# Is there any possible way to access the xml value using loop?

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I have stored the xml structure into a string **abcd**.

```
    string abcd="<xmlstruct>
    <test>
        <name>testname</name>
        <address>testaddress</address>
        <subject>testsub<subject>
    </test>

    <test1>
        <name>testname1</name>
        <address>testaddress1</address>
        <subject>testsub<subject>
    </test1>

    <test2>
        <name>testname2</name>
        <address>testaddress2</address>
        <subject>testsub2<subject>
    </test2>

    <test3>
        <name>testname3</name>
        <address>testaddress3</address>
        <subject>testsub3<subject>
    </test3>


    </xmlstruct>";
```

I retrieved the xml values from the string like,

```
var xElem = XElement.Parse(abcd);
string getname =  xElem.Element("test").Element("name").Value;
string getname1 = xElem.Element("test1").Element("name").Value;
string getname2 = xElem.Element("test2").Element("name").Value;
string getname3 = xElem.Element("test3").Element("name").Value;
```

It was working fine.My question is,**"Is there any possible way to make the loop and get the test,test1,test2,test3 values?"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice for `"test0"` is a bit irregular but this should do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   string suffix = i > 0 ? i.ToString() : "";
   string getname =  xElem.Element("test"+suffix).Element("name").Value;
   ...
}
```

But you probably should look into a better XML structure, something like

```
<test id="1">
    <name>testname2</name>
    <address>testaddress2</address>
    <subject>testsub2<subject>
</test>
```

Comment: can u please elaborate.because am new to handle xml

Comment: I can only elaborate when you indicate what you need to do with it.

Comment: Might want to change those `x`'s to `i`'s, or vice versa :p

Comment: @HenkHolterman Holterman string suffix = x > 0 ? x.ToString() : ""; in this statement what does  x represent ?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `i`. Edited.